# Scraping image with bs4 python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

here is the link  "https://www.blocket.se/annons/stockholm/samsung_note10__i_nyskick_med_kvitto/92119857"

and i want to extract an image of phone

```
"<div style="left:0%;background-image:url(https://i.blocketcdn.se/pictures/2835058804.jpg?type=original);width:100%;height:100%;background-size:contain;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;position:absolute"></div>"
```

when i search with find_all, i get background image and not the one i want ( phone ), or None

Anyone with the idea how to extract just an phone image

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the image url from `<meta ...>` tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.blocket.se/annons/stockholm/samsung_note10__i_nyskick_med_kvitto/92119857'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

img_url = soup.select_one('[property="og:image"]')['content']
img_url_original = img_url.split('?')[0] + '?type=original'

print(img_url_original)
```

Prints:

```
https://i.blocketcdn.se/pictures/2835058804.jpg?type=original
```